# Unix: find directory filenames listed in a text file and move to new directory

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I'm a command line novice trying to figure out the appropriate command to execute the following within the Terminal in Mac OS X.

Assuming I've placed all files in the same directory, I want to isolate and move a selected set of files listed in a text file in that directory to a new directory, how do I:

- read the selected list of filenames listed in a .txt file
- find all matches by filename
- isolate and move all file matches to a new directory

I've found this to find either or both a filestring.filetype in a current directory and move all matches to a new directory:

```
find . -type f -iname "*filestring*.filetype" -print0| xargs -0 -J % mv % ~/NewDirectory/
```

And I've found this tar command however it creates an archive copy of each filename listed in ‘filename.txt’

```
tar -cf - -T filename.txt |(cd /path/to/new/dir && tar -xvf -)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

I received an effective solution from a trusted source:

```
cat "filename.txt" | xargs -I % mv % ~/NewDirectory/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read filename
do 
  mv "$filename" ~/NewDirectory/
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the following bash error: -bash: read: `fn.txt': not a valid identifier

Comment: It should be `while read filename`, not `while read fn.txt`. The parameter to `read` is a variable to assign each input line to, not the name of the file you're reading from (that goes after `<` at the end).

Comment: Understood, Thank-you! Now when calling: done > fn.txt I get this: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments, edit it into your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, where is the appropriate place to edit code into my question?

Comment: Any other ideas on how to execute?

Comment: What does "syntax error near unexpected token 'done'" indicate?

Comment: It indicates that the "while blah; do" was not seen correctly.

Comment: Any ideas on why this would happen and/or any other script ideas?

Comment: Maybe you pasted some non-printing characters?

Comment: I typed it letter for letter.  I've got bash 3.2

Comment: This is really simple, basic syntax that has worked for decades. I copied what you posted and it works, so you must be typing something different.

Comment: I understand.  I've tried this at least 30 times.  I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, how do I figure it out?

Comment: After you type the first line, do you get a `>` prompt for the rest of the lines?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, after some troubleshooting, turns out carriage returns were not being properly translated from Excel to the .txt file

Comment: I was going to ask what editor you used, but you said you typed it into the terminal.